# RaisedButton not working at all

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have included material-ui (and react-tap-event-plugin) in my project and added 3 buttons to one of my components:

```
<RaisedButton onClick={this.props.onSave} label="Save" style={styles.button}/>
<RaisedButton label='Publish' onClick={this.props.onPublish} style={styles.button}/>
<RaisedButton label='Cancel' onClick={this.onCancel.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonCancel}/>
```

when I click on any of these, they go very dark grey and when I click again, they go black (and stay like that). The whole applications goes bonkers, the react routing no longer works (I can see the URL changing in the address bar, but the view doesn't refresh). This all looks pretty bad for a button click :)

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? (I take care of the childContext as described in the docs, so the muiTheme is loaded).

I forgot to check the console... there are 3 exceptions whenever I press the button:

1)
vendor.js:12 Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).(…)

2) 
ReactTransitionGroup.js:176 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentWillLeave' of undefined(…)

3)
vendor.js:12 Uncaught Error: removeComponentAsRefFrom(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be removing a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).(…)

In the component that uses FlatButton (or RaisedButton neither work) I have this:

1) Import:
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';  //eslint-disable-line
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

2) in the class
    getChildContext() {
        return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
    }

3) and a static declaration:
EditorComponent.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

Feels like I'm doing all that's required.

This may be related to what I'm experiencing:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2818

So probably the issue is caused by material-ui distributing it's own version of React? What's the point in that? But... my version of material-ui doesn't have a node_modules folder, so no extra React either...

Source for a component importing and using FlatButton

```
import React from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line
import Input from '../../../components/common/textInput';  // eslint-disable-line
import BaseEditorComponent from '../base/EditorComponent';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';  //eslint-disable-line
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';


export default class EditorComponent extends BaseEditorComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            textValue: 'Enter value'
        };
    }
    getChildContext() {
        return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
    }

    _onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            textValue: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Input
                    value={this.state.textValue}
                    name="SimpleText"
                    label="Simple Text Value:"
                    onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                <FlatButton label="Test"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


EditorComponent.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Also, the BaseEditorComponent:

```
import React from 'react';
import widgetActions from '../../widgets/WidgetActions';
import widgetInstanceStore from '../../widgets/WidgetInstanceStore';

export default class EditorComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState(widgetInstanceStore.getWidgetInstanceState(this.props.widgetId) || {});
    }
    save() {
        widgetActions.saveWidgetInstanceState(this.props.widgetId, this.state);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've now tested with FlatButton, it doesn't go completely black (or darker on 2nd click) but otherwise, same problem.

Comment: Have you included the styles?

Comment: Yes, if you mean the object referred to in the style attribute, that's a valid reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to use onTouchTap instead of onClick?
2. If #1 doesn't help, please show more code - component with above code and it's parent component.

Comment: onTouchTap behaves the same unfortunately. I can try to show more code, but my impression from google search that I may be loading two copies of React somehow. Although after removing the node_modules and doing an npm install and then an npm list react I only got one instance listed, so I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Yes, pls see attached to the original post. I've done a little debugging and it seems the owner is null for this component, which is a tell tale sign of multiple react instances having been loaded. Not sure why that is though, npm reports 1 instance. Other 3rd party components load fine. This is certainly one big trap around react, many reports of similar issues, hours wasted to debugging. React could do a bit more to defend against this situation.

Comment: Any chances you attach full body of your react class?

Comment: Sure. I've tried to inject this button into various classes, I'll attach a simple one in a sec.

Comment: I've updated the question with the source of a simple component using FlatButton. (I've removed the event handling as it's not needed to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: And the BaseEditorComponent ...?

Comment: Included now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127526/discussion-between-piotr-soltysiak-and-janos).

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2818 the solution was to include react-addons-transition-group alongside react in the browserify bundle. So it's good to know that it's not only NPM where a 2nd copy of react can slip through, but also browserify or webpack.

Thanks [https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706986/piotr-sołtysiak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706986/piotr-so%C5%82tysiak) for helping with the issue today!